How to get a random word from 3 different text files I have stored in the Assets folder when players click a button
I have 3 buttons at this time: 3, 4 and 5.
What I need to do: every time a player chooses 3, 4 or 5, he will get a random word assigned to him from a .txt file
Text files are 3pointWordList, 4pointWordList and 5pointWordList, all currently inside a Assets\\Word Lists folder.
If a player chooses 3 points now, the next time it's the player's turn, he will have to choose one of the other 2 options.
My current issue is that I cant get a random word from the txt files. ChatGPT doesn't help, other questions on stackoverflow/stackexchange also didn't help.
I went with just defining each button to have a set wordListNumber inside the inspector so button 3 has wordListNumebr 3 and so on. Also after the word was selected it should be deleted from the next randomize pool.
Code that didn't work for the randomize:
int randomIndex = Random.Range(0, wordList.Count);
string selectedWord = wordList[randomIndex];
wordList.RemoveAt(randomIndex);

My code:
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine.UIElements;

public class TaskManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int wordListNumber;
    public string wordList;
    public string selectedWord;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        if (wordListNumber == 3)
        { 
        }
        else if (wordListNumber == 4)
        {
        }
        else if (wordListNumber == 5)
        {
        }    
    }
}

EDIT 1:
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using UnityEditor.Experimental.GraphView;
using TMPro;

public class RandomWordLoader : MonoBehaviour
{
public string fileName = "3pointWordList";
public string fileName2 = "4pointWordList";
public string fileName3 = "5pointWordList";
public int pointquestion;
public TextMeshProUGUI yourWord;


private List<string> lines = new List<string>();

void Start()
{
    LoadWordsFromFile();
}

void LoadWordsFromFile()
{
    if (pointquestion == 3)
    { 
        TextAsset textAsset = Resources.Load<TextAsset>(fileName);

        if (textAsset != null)
        {
            StringReader reader = new StringReader(textAsset.text);
            string line;

            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                // Assuming each line contains one word
                lines.Add(line.Trim());
            }

            reader.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError("Failed to load file: " + fileName);
        }

    }
    else if (pointquestion == 4)
    {
        TextAsset textAsset = Resources.Load<TextAsset>(fileName2);

        if (textAsset != null)
        {
            StringReader reader = new StringReader(textAsset.text);
            string line;

            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                // Assuming each line contains one word
                lines.Add(line.Trim());
            }

            reader.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError("Failed to load file: " + fileName);
        }

    }
    else if (pointquestion == 5)
    {
        TextAsset textAsset = Resources.Load<TextAsset>(fileName3);

        if (textAsset != null)
        {
            StringReader reader = new StringReader(textAsset.text);
            string line;

            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                // Assuming each line contains one word
                lines.Add(line.Trim());
            }

            reader.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError("Failed to load file: " + fileName);
        }

    }
}
public string GetRandomWord()
{
    if (lines.Count > 0)
    {
        int randomIndex = Random.Range(0, lines.Count);
        return lines[randomIndex];


    }
    else
    {
        Debug.LogWarning("No words loaded.");
        return null;
    }
}

}

You can expose a public TextAsset[] in your MonoBehaviour so you can assign them in your Editor. You then index into this array and read the selected file

Based on what you posted, you never actually assign anything to wordList, so of course you can't index it. You would have to assign the appropriate list of words to wordList first, in that second code snippet, in order for the first code snippet to work.

Ask ChatGPT a better question, like: "Why does below unity code not get a random word from 3 different text files I have stored in the Assets folder when players click a button using this code, please do not provide example solutions:"  (or learn how to debug your own code, which is a better option!)

Your initial code snippet should have worked, as long as there were items in the list and indeed that wordList was an array or list of words:
List<string> wordList = new List<string> { "one", "two", "three", "four", "five" };
int randomIndex = Random.Range(0, wordList.Count);
string selectedWord = wordList[randomIndex];
wordList.RemoveAt(randomIndex);

System.Console.WriteLine("Selected Word: {0}", selectedWord);
System.Console.WriteLine("Remaining Words: {0}", System.String.Join(", ", wordList));

Selected Word: three
Remaining Words: one, two, four, five

But looking at the rest of your code, wordList is declared as a string and not any form of array of strings. It is also not clear where you have sourced the strings from. So using this more complete sample I hope you can adapt your code.

When you experience issues during development it is better to post any exceptions or compiler messages as that can focus the discussion.
if you update you post with some code that you have used to try to load the word list from a file, we can help you with that as it looks like that is the only remaining issue.


Update - Code Review
It is still not obvious what is wrong with the updated code, but there is a lot of redundancy in your logic so lets clean it up
void LoadWordsFromFile()
{
    string selectedFilename = filename;
    if (pointquestion == 4)
        selectedFilename = fileName2;
    else if (pointquestion == 5)
        selectedFilename = fileName3
    
    TextAsset textAsset = Resources.Load<TextAsset>(fileName);
    if (textAsset != null)
    {
        StringReader reader = new StringReader(textAsset.text);
        string line;

        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            // Assuming each line contains one word
            lines.Add(line.Trim());
        }

        reader.Close();
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.LogError("Failed to load file: " + selectedFilename);
    }
}


The problem with code clones is that if you need to fix or edit the general replicated logic, then you need to remember to make those changes in the other places as well, far better to simplify your logic by identifying the variables and refactoring the logic around those.

This should work fine, GetRandomWord() looks good too, so I'm not sure where you are having issues, but it is most likely that the files you are trying to load do not match the filenames you are using in the code, or the files are not actually in the assets folder.

I have added the code I am using to read the text files.

And so what is the problem? Does lines have values or are you getting the "No words loaded" message? Happy to help here but you need to provide the debugging details, not just post code.
